# Docker user permissions in mounted volumes

Tags: bash, docker

I am running some docker images that need to mount a local volume and make changes there. I am launching the container with a typical

`docker run -it -v $(pwd):/root/foo ${IMAGENAME} ./script.sh`

The problem is that new files in host directory have root permission/owner. I would prefer avoiding any configuration except from adding something to the command line.

Changing the file permissions after executing would not be clean enough and may require root permissions anyway.

Ideally I would like something like `--userns-remap` but applied when I execute docker run and mapping the container root to the user that launched the container.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what your problem is. By default, all files inside a container will be owned by the container's root user. Is that a behaviour you do not want ? If so, you'll have to create a new user inside your container, and chown/chmod the folders you need to. The best way to do that would be through a Dockerfile with `RUN` directives.

Comment: I updated the question. I was thinking something like `--userns-remap` would be possible in `docker run`

Comment: @Aserre the problem is that any new file in a mounted volume is has root as owner in the host directory, even if the container was lauched as a normal `myuser123`

Answer (score 0):

You have different options to fix this. 
1)Without modifying the docker image or the Dockerfile, you can change the permission of the files in the folder with 
"$ sudo chmod -R 777 /path/foo"

or if you want to be sure that whoever takes this image is ok with permissions, do some changes to the Dockerfile, like change permissions inside the container or write the file in a /home/foo folder.

I hope you understood what to do, or at least got an idea.

Comment: well.. I am actually looking for a cleaner way of doing this.
option 1 would be just patching the issue and requires root permissions. option 2 requires knowing the UID/GID of the user that is launching the container. 
At the moment, I am actually inheriting UID/GID and creating a user but I guess that something similar to user namespaces should be possible.